# After loading the urdf model in gazebo, there is no `map` frame on the tf tree

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I defined a robot model with the `urdf` file, but after gazebo reads the urdf file, I check out the `tf` tree and find that there is no `map` frame on the `tf` tree. I wanna figure out how I can generate a map frame when I spawn my robot model in gazebo. Any advice will be appreciated.

Screenshot of tf tree:
[image: Imgur]

My launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Launch this file to spawn cambot model in gazebo. -->
<launch>
    <!-- these are the arguments you can pass this launch file, for example paused:=true -->
    <arg name="paused" default="false" />
    <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true" />
    <arg name="gui" default="true" />
    <arg name="headless" default="false" />
    <arg name="debug" default="false" />
    <!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch, changing only the name of the world to be launched -->
    <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
        <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)" />
        <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
        <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)" />
        <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)" />
        <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)" />
    </include>
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find cambot_description)/urdf/cambot.urdf.xacro" />
    <node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" respawn="false" output="screen" args="-urdf -model cambot -param robot_description"></node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320066/after-loading-the-urdf-model-in-gazebo,-there-is-no-%60map%60-frame-on-the-tf-tree./) by [anonymous38087](https://answers.ros.org/users/38087/anonymous38087/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2019-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem of getting the `map -> odom` transformation is essentially the robot localization problem. So, if you have a map of the environment, you can use a ROS localization package like [robot_pose_ekf](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf) or [AMCL](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) depending on the type of map and the sensors available.

However, if what you need is a simple pose for the robot, you can use the `libgazebo_ros_p3d.so` gazebo plugin as used [here](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/taurob_tracker_common/blob/master/taurob_tracker_description/urdf/tracker_chassis.gazebo.xacro.xml#L44).

It will publish a `nav_message/Odometry` message to the specified topic. This message essentially is the `map -> base_link` transformation. You can manipulate this information to publish a `/tf` yourself. Since ROS
[doesn't allow multiple parent frames](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/FAQ#Frames_are_missing_in_my_tf_tree._Why.3F), you can't simply publish a `/tf` using [message_to_tf](http://wiki.ros.org/message_to_tf). You will need to publish `map -> odom` by subtracting `odom -> base_link` from `map -> base_link`. A clear example is given in the [AMCL implementation](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/melodic-devel/amcl/src/amcl_node.cpp#L1409).

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2019-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous38087](https://answers.ros.org/users/38087/anonymous38087/) on 2019-04-02**:
Actually, I want to run [cartographer](https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in gazebo with a simulated robot described by `urdf` format. I defined a laser gazebo plugin to get the simulated lidar data, but because there is no `map` frame in the `tf` tree, I can't get the map produced by the `cartographer`  node.

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-04-02**:
Publishing the `map` frame in the `tf` tree is the responsibility of the SLAM / Localization algorithm. And Cartographer does that. Are you sure you have configured it properly? You can take a look at the [lua config](https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html). You need to set the `map_frame`, `tracking_frame` and `published_frame` properly.

**Comment by [anonymous38087](https://answers.ros.org/users/38087/anonymous38087/) on 2019-04-02**:
Now I know the reason: the robot model I generated in gazebo was started in `empty world`(`roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch`), causing the data of the simulated laser to be all 0. Now I generate the robot in a world with some obstacles(`roslaunch gazebo_ros shapes_world.launch`), `cartographer` will update the `map->odom` transform on the tf tree according to the non-zero `sensor_msgs/LaserScan` data.

**Comment by [anonymous38087](https://answers.ros.org/users/38087/anonymous38087/) on 2019-04-02**:
Thank you, sir!